# specific columns in database using sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle

i wanna search about specific columns in specific schema 
column name for example description

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest option is to connect to that "specific" schema and run

```
SQL> select table_name
  2  from user_tab_columns
  3  where column_name = 'DEPTNO';

TABLE_NAME
------------------------------
DEPT
EMP

SQL>
```

Alternatively, in order to query ALL tables you have access to, query `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` instead.

If you have required privileges and can connect as, for example, SYS, query `DBA_TAB_COLUMNS`. In that case, include the OWNER column:

```
SQL> select owner, table_name
  2  from dba_tab_columns
  3  where column_name = 'DEPTNO';

OWNER                          TABLE_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
MIKE                           DEPT
MIKE                           EMP
SCOTT                          EMP
SCOTT                          DEPT
<snip>
```